# How to call a variable from another class in C# (mobile app)

Tags: c#, class, variables

I'm working on Visual Studio 2019.
I have a variable named "batt_lev" which is in BatteryAlert.Android -> BatteryService1.cs
I need to call this variable in the shared code in MainPage.xaml.cs in a method named "void Etichetta()" where i have to use the variable.
I tried to use BatteryService1.batt_lev, as you can see, but the error is "no BatteryService1 in this context".

Can someone help me?

**MainPage.xaml.cs** in the shared code

```
namespace BatteryAlert
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private double batt_lev;
        


        public MainPage()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
            DependencyService.Get<IUpLoad>().upLoad();
            //Etichetta();
            //DependencyService.Get<IAndroidService>().StartServicee();
            //Battery.BatteryInfoChanged += Battery_BatteryInfoChanged;
            

        }

        void Etichetta()
        {
            
            //Battery.BatteryInfoChanged += Battery_BatteryInfoChanged;
 
            batt_lev = (float)Battery.ChargeLevel;
            CounterLabel.Text = BatteryService1.batt_lev.ToString("N2");
        }
    }
}
```

**BatteryService1.cs** in BatteryAlert.Android

```
namespace BatteryAlert.Droid
{
    [Service(Name = "com.companyname.BatteryAlert.BatteryService1")]
    public class BatteryService1 : JobIntentService
    {
        private static int MY_JOB_ID = 1000;
        public double batt_lev;
        List<double> valoreControllo = new List<double>()
        {
            0.65, 0.60, 0.55, 0.50, 0.45, 0.40, 0.35, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.10, 0.05
        };


        protected override void OnHandleWork(Intent p0)
        {
            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10), () =>
            {
                // do something every 10 seconds
                Battery.BatteryInfoChanged += Battery_BatteryInfoChanged;
                //DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("suono_123.wav");
                return true; // runs again, or false to stop
            });
            
        }

        public static void EnqueueWork(Context context, Intent work)
        {
            Java.Lang.Class cls = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(BatteryService1));

            try
            {
                EnqueueWork(context, cls, MY_JOB_ID, work);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            }

        }

        void Battery_BatteryInfoChanged(Object sender, BatteryInfoChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            batt_lev = (double)e.ChargeLevel;
            batt_lev = Math.Round(batt_lev, 2);

            if (valoreControllo.Contains(batt_lev))
            {
                //CounterLabel.Text = batt_lev.ToString("N2");
                DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("suono_123.wav");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: batt_lev is not static, so you have to instantiate BatteryService1 to access it. It seems you are using Dependency Injection, so you should inject BatteryService1 in order to use it

Comment: ok, I have read something on inernet, it seems very complicated, keep in mind I used and adapted the code above, so I don't know how "inject BatteryService1". Can you give me some other tips? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a variable from another class you should have that class being derived for the class you want to use it.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
```

If you want to still have the MainPage derived for the ContentPage you should derive the class you want (BatteryService1) to the ContentPage or vice-versa. Like this:

```
public class ContentPage : BatteryService1
```